# Left-luggage facility in George Airport, South Africa

Tags: airports, south-africa, luggage-storage

Is there left-luggage storage available in George Airport, South Africa?

Comment: George is a pretty small airport. I'd be surprised if it has luggage storage facilities. You could [contact them](http://www.airports.co.za/airports/george-airport/the-airport/contact-us) and ask.

Answer (score 1):

There is no luggage storage available, according to [George Airport's](http://www.airports.co.za/airports/george-airport/the-airport/shops-facilities) facility and services information. The independent [Sleeping in Airports](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/africa/george-airport.htm) confirms that information.

An alternative could be to make arrangements at an area hotel, B&B, or hostel.